# War card game in C

Tags: c

Beginner coder here. I am currently taking a class where I have to make a card war game in a c program. I have a segmentation fault and I'm pretty sure it's happening in my queue/enqueue/dequeue functions. Can anyone help me?

This isn't all the code, just a smaller test case I used to figure out I have a segmentation fault.

Edit: posted all the code instead

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

/// Valid cards in our deck
/// 2
/// 3
/// ...
/// 9
/// 10
/// Jack  = 11
/// Queen = 12
/// King  = 13
/// Ace   = 14

//global variables
struct Deck{
    struct Card* Top;
};

struct Card{
    int value;
    struct Card* next;
};

struct Deck* plyhand1;
struct Deck* plyhand2;

#define deckSize 52

int* deck; //Complete deck of cards
struct Deck* pile; //Pile of flipped cards
int rounds = 0;
int num_war = 0;
int flip1 = 0;
int flip2 = 0;
int cards = 0;
int localwar = 0;


void enqueue(struct Deck* queue, int item){
    //Creates new card to add to deck and gives it a value
    struct Card* newCard = malloc(sizeof(struct Card));
    newCard->next = NULL;
    newCard->value = item;
    item = 0;

    if(queue->Top == NULL){ // checks if deck is empty
        queue->Top = newCard;
        return;
}else{
    struct Card* h = queue->Top;
    while(h->next!=NULL){// Loops to the end of the queue
        h = h->next;
    }
    h->next = newCard; // Adds card to the end of the queue
}
return;
}

///USED FOR REMOVING THINGS FROM HAND EASIER
///PRE: deck size during play
///POST: returns value of the top card if deck is not empty
int dequeue(struct Deck* queue){
    if(queue->Top == NULL){ // Checks if deck is empty
        return -1;
    }
    int temp = queue->Top->value; // takes values of top of the deck
    struct Card* t = queue->Top;
```

I think this is where the seg fault is happening

```
        if(queue->Top->next == NULL) queue->Top = NULL; // deletes top card from the deck

        else{ queue->Top = queue->Top->next; }

        free(t);
    return temp;
}






void shuffle(int* array){
    int n = 52;
    if (n > 1){
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < n - 1; i++){
            /// get  random element in the listplayer1Hand[26] = 2;
            int j = i + rand() / (RAND_MAX / (n - i) + 1);

            ///swap these two elements
            int temp = array[j];
            array[j] = array[i];
            array[i] = temp;
        }
    }
}

///Players hands
//deals the entire deck to the two players
//PRE: entire array containing the entire deck of cards
//OUTPUT: gives 26 shuffled cards to each player
void deal(int* d){
    int count=1;
    while(count<53){
        if(count%2!=0) enqueue(plyhand1, *deck); //Gives card to player1
        else{
            enqueue(plyhand2, *deck); //Gives card to player2
        }
        count++;
    }
}

//when flip cards equal each other, declare war
//PRE: war is declared when the first two flipped cards equal each other
//POST: flips cards until one player wins, increases number of wars while flip1=flip2 with while loop
void war(){
    while (flip1==flip2){
        num_war++;
        localwar++;

        //Flips another hand of cards
        flip1=dequeue(plyhand1);
        flip2=dequeue(plyhand2);

        //Adds flipped cards to pile deck
        enqueue(pile, flip1);
        enqueue(pile, flip2);

        //Checks value of cards
        if(flip1>10){
            switch(flip1){
                case 11:
                    printf("Jack");
                case 12:
                    printf("Queen");
                case 13:
                    printf("King");
                case 14:
                    printf("Ace");
                default:
                    printf("Error");
                    break;
            }
        }
        else{
            printf("Player 1: %d\n", flip1);
        }
        if(flip2>10){
            switch(flip2){
                case 11:
                    printf("Jack");
                case 12:
                    printf("Queen");
                case 13:
                    printf("King");
                case 14:
                    printf("Ace");
                default:
                    printf("Error");
                    break;
            }
        }
        else{ printf("Player 2: %d\n", flip1); }
    }
    /*If cards are still equal while loop will execute again,
     otherwise the function will return to play() */

    return;
}

///Game logic
//PRE: empty player hands
//OUTPUT: the card flipped, winner of game, & cards won by player
void play(int* d){
    plyhand1 = malloc(sizeof(struct Deck));
    plyhand1->Top = malloc(sizeof(struct Card *)); 
    plyhand2 = malloc(sizeof(struct Deck));
    plyhand2->Top = malloc(sizeof(struct Card *));

    deal(d);
    while(plyhand1->Top!=NULL && plyhand2->Top!=NULL){
        rounds++;
        flip1=dequeue(plyhand1);
        flip2=dequeue(plyhand2);
        enqueue(pile, flip1);
        enqueue(pile, flip2);
        //flipping check
        if(flip1>10){
            switch(flip1){
                case 11:
                    printf("Jack");
                case 12:
                    printf("Queen");
                case 13:
                    printf("King");
                case 14:
                    printf("Ace");
                default:
                    printf("Error");
                    break;
            }
        }
        else{ printf("Player 1: %d\n", flip1); }

        if(flip2>10){
            switch(flip2){
                case 11:
                    printf("Jack");
                case 12:
                    printf("Queen");
                case 13:
                    printf("King");
                case 14:
                    printf("Ace");
                default:
                    printf("Error");
                    break;
            }
        }else{ printf("Player 2: %d\n", flip2); }
        //end of flipping check
        if(flip1==flip2){
            int localwar = 0;
            war(); //if two cards equal each other, declare war
            cards += (localwar * 2);
        }

        if(flip1 < flip2){
            cards += 2;
            printf("Player 2 wins (%d) cards!\n", cards);
            while(pile->Top!=NULL){
                enqueue(plyhand2, dequeue(pile));
            }

        }
        else
        {
            while(pile->Top!=NULL){
                enqueue(plyhand1, dequeue(pile));
            }
            cards += 2;
            printf("Player 1 wins (%d) cards!\n", cards);

        }
        printf("Rounds won: (%d) \n", rounds);
        printf("Wars Declared: (%d) \n", num_war);
    }
    free(plyhand2);
    free(plyhand1);
}

int main(){
    /// random number generator seed
    srand(time(NULL));

    deck = malloc(sizeof( int) * 52 );

    /* deck = malloc(52 * sizeof(int)); */
    /// Make our deck
    int i, j, count = 0;
    for(i = 0;i < 4;i++){
        for(j = 2;j < 15;j++){
            deck[count] = j;
            count++;
        }
    }

    /// Shuffle Our Deck
    shuffle(deck);

    //Plays game
    play(deck);

    /* free(deck); */
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: well, pile is not initialized to point to anything in your example code

Comment: you're not allocating any memory for `pile`. As soon as you do `queue->` in `enqueue` you're invoking undefined behavior.

Comment: my bad, forgot to add it in my example code. Thanks!

Comment: still your bad, it's still not pointing to anything

Comment: if you run your code in a debugger like `gdb` it will show you exactly where the line of code that hits the exception is.  You can then show the values of the variables that are causing the problem

Comment: `pile` definitely needs to be initialized as @KeithNicholas states.  I think that you would crash in enqueue first.

Answer (score 0):

you have a lot of pointers that don't point to things, you need to allocate memory for them, perhaps something like

```
struct Deck* newDeck() {
    struct Deck* p = malloc(sizeof(struct Deck));
    p->Top = NULL;
    return p;
}

void displayDeck(struct Deck* deck)
{
    if(deck == NULL)
    {
        printf("No Deck\r\n");
        return;
    }
    struct Card* p = deck->Top;
    while(p != NULL)
    {
        printf("%d\r\n", p->value);
        p = p->next;
    }
}

int main() {

    pile = newDeck();

    enqueue(pile, 2);
    enqueue(pile, 3);
    enqueue(pile, 4);

    displayDeck(pile);

    printf("%d\r\n", dequeue(pile));
    printf("%d\r\n", dequeue(pile));
    printf("%d\r\n", dequeue(pile));
    printf("%d\r\n", dequeue(pile));    

    return 0;
}
```

[image]

Also

```
if (queue->Top->next == NULL) queue->Top = NULL;     
else { queue->Top = queue->Top->next; }
```

is just the same as

```
queue->Top = queue->Top->next;
```